# Is $ \ {y}'' + \sin\ {y '} = 0 $ Differential Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, derivatives, polynomials, systems-of-equations

$$
       \ {y}'' + \sin\ {y '} = 0 
$$

**Order is 2**

**While degree is not defined.**

*Is this a differential equation ?*

*If yes , then why is the degree not defined ?*

*If no ,  then why is the order defined if it is not a differential equation ?*

Comment: What's the degree of a DE?

Comment: Degree is not defined, i.e. the equation is not in the form of a polynomial in it's derivatives. It is however, indeed a (nonlinear) homogenous differential equation of order 2.

Comment: Look at for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2917742/find-order-and-degree-of-a-differential-equation

Answer (score 0):

It is a Ordinary Differential Equation, Second-Order, Non-linear, and the basis of my answer is coming of the First course in Differential Equations by Dennis Zill.